# How to use ClearCase annotate sub-command?

Tags: clearcase, annotate

I'm trying to find out how to get a code history report in which I get the file version for each of code line. 
I don't need to get multiple rows for each code line. only one.
The 'annotate' sub-command has many arguments and I can't find the good one for that purpose. Do you know how to get that?

Many thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901563/how-to-use-clearcase-annotate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the file version for each of code line

That almost looks like the last example of the [cleartool annotate](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_annotate.htm) command:

```
cleartool annotate -out - -fmt "%Vn |" -rm -nheader util.c
```

Meaning: no header, only text line annotations, including the deleted ones.