# How to use ClearCase Annotate

Tags: clearcase, annotate

I'm trying to use annotate but have a problem: The output ignores some information (date and username) if it was displayed for the same version before. I'd like to display them in any line.

This is my command:

```
cleartool annotate -out - -rm -nhe -fmt "%Sd ||| %-12.12u ||| %Vn ||| ,,%Vn |||  " -rmf "" "G:\views\myview\myprojectvob\Form1.frm@@\main\john_myprject\12"
```

That's the output. I'd like to get date and username for the second and third lines as well.
Do you know if that's possible?

```
2008-05-22 ||| john           ||| \main\john_myproject\10 ||| End Sub
                                  \main\john_myproject\10 |||
                                  \main\john_myproject\10 ||| Private Sub mnuContents_Click()
                                  \main\john_myproject\10 |||   On Error GoTo errHandle
                                  \main\john_myproject\10 |||
                                  \main\john_myproject\10 |||   Dim stat As Integer
                                  \main\john_myproject\10 |||   stat = ExecuteLink(App.path & "\manual.pdf")
                                  \main\john_myproject\10 |||
                                  \main\john_myproject\10 |||   Exit Sub
                                  \main\john_myproject\10 ||| errHandle:
                                  \main\john_myproject\10 |||   MsgBox ("Error with PDF file")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`cleartool annotate` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_annotate.htm), that command always uses an "elide-format", precisely to avoid duplicating informations on lines modified by the same author.

So the only solution would be to parse the result of that command in order to insert the relevant information.

Comment: My manual speaks of a `-f` option to force full output without elision.

Comment: @SimonRichter: yes, maybe the OP can use that kind of output as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use -force to get rid of that (.) character. 
This is what I am using for my script - 
`cleartool annotate -all -fmt "%Ad %-8.8u %-100.150Vn | "  -nheader -force <filename>`