# How to find activities of a modified files in Clearcase

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have a file `test.cpp` somebody added a few lines of code i don't know when but i'm assuming it was in a specific range of time that i know.I want to find the activity that was used to deliever this changes, i found a lot of versions of this element in the version tree of this element, but all the activities that i was able to see were as a result of a rebase, i need to find the source activity that was in charge of adding this few lines of code.
Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

For each deliver activity (that you can see in the version tree), you can list the contributing activities with

```
cleartool lsact -contrib activity:anact@/apvob # on unix @/vobs/apvob
```

See "[Finding which developer activities were delivered in a specific delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14022262/6309)"

Then you need to describe each activity found, to see if your file is in it.

```
cleartool descr -l activity:anact@/avob
```

Obviously, you also can use a [`cleartool annotate`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_annotate.htm), in order to see the versions in that file: see "[How to use ClearCase Annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901788/6309)".
If you see one line which interest you, check its version n# 'x' and use `cleartool descr -l file@/main/.../x` to find its corresponding activity.

Comment: How can i find if the current version was created as a result of a merge and if it was merged how can i find the version of the original file that was merged

Comment: @user3502786 if it was merged how can i find the version of the original file that was merged: `cleartool lsact -contrib activity:deliver_anact@/apvob`

Comment: I've tried to use `lsact -contrib`  then checked the changeset of each activity that was listed i didn't find the relevant `.cpp` file that was changed any idea why ?

Comment: @user3502786 not sure why. But "if it was merged how can i find the version of the original file that was merged": you should see a red merge arrow in the version tree of that file in the version tree (the must be a way to get it by script too)

Comment: If i'm wrong and this file wasn't merged, there is any way to determine what is original activity which inserted this change

Comment: @user3502786 mainly through `cleartool annotate`, lookking at the version which matches the change you are looking for in this file.

Comment: can you give me some example?
This is the version that i found in the change set of the latest activity:
`/ccstore/builder/hudson/workspace/RavenPlat2.0.0.0_Chassis_Recommended/builder_RavenPlat2.0.0.0_Chassis_Recommended/vobs/ravenp/RavenBlocks@@/main/alonma_Raven_Inter/2/Filters/main/Raven_Inter_Integ/RavenApp1.2.2_Integ/eyalsa_RavenAppMain_1/4/DataPathNewCommOutFlt/main/eyalsa_RavenAppMain_1/2/src/main/eyalsa_RavenAppMain_1/2/rvnDataPathEgressProcessor.cpp/main/RavenAppMain_Integ/RavenApp1.5/RavenApp1.5.0.0_Integ/RavenApp1.6.0.0_Integ_OBS/RavenApp1.5.2.0_Integ/RavenApp1.5.5.0_Integ/15`

Comment: @user3502786 look at the examples of https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_annotate.htm

Comment: By the way once i right click on this version (15) in the version tree, and open the properties -> custom i can see there `Hyperlinks` 
What are this Hyperlinks mean ?

Comment: @user3502786 it can represent the red arrow I was mentioning in case of a merge: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7464236/6309

Comment: I found the baseline that was used in the rebase operation, how can i get some info regarding this baseline, who created this baseline and some other useful details that will lead me to the source activity

Comment: @user3502786 if the baseline name starts with deliver: see my answer above.

Comment: the baseline doesn't start with 'deliver', it's seems to be a regular baseline in the same format as the previous baselines

Comment: @user3502786 then it doesn't mean your file was modified by it: if it is a full baseline, you file would have been labelled, modification or not. You need to go back in the version tree, until you see a red arrow (merge), to look for that activity at the origin of it.

Comment: The thing is that the first change that i can see was made during a rebase, but i can't locate the source version that created this baseline

Comment: @user3502786 you should see it on the version tree though.

Comment: Can you have a look on my screen? i'll give you my teamviewer id

Comment: @user3502786 not from work, sorry, may be in a few hours at home.

Comment: Ok, let me know what's your email address so i'll be able to send you the details