# Appending line in file when changes were made

Tags: comparison, cleartool, winmerge

I am looking for a file comparison tool (like WinMerge) that will compare the text of the files AND on the lines that were changed let me append a comment to the end of the line such as "`//changed by bob`".
The file would then be saved with the changes the developer made and with the added comment on every line changed.

I have found ways to log changes to a file but not a way to append the file that is being committed.

We are using ClearCase as source control so we have access to `cleartool`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such a tool.

The closest you might consider would be [`cleartool annotate`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_annotate.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-0) (see "[How to use ClearCase Annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7901563/6309)").
You could process the output of this command in order to regenerate the file content with the right information added to each line.