# Clearcase file search with function level changes

Tags: clearcase

Is there an easy way to check in which file version the function has been modified in Clearcase? In my current environment I have file where the function is modified in some prior check-ins. On doing compare with previous version, it is not the one. So I have to go and compare with all previous check-ins to figure out in which version this has been modified. So is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Do you use UCM or Base?

Comment: We use UCM for Clearcase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [cleartool annotate](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_annotate.htm) function

> The annotate command lists the contents of a version, annotating each line to indicate when, and in which version, the line was added. You can customize the annotations using the `–fmt` option, which is described in the [`fmt_ccase` reference page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc%2Ftopics%2Ffmt_ccase.htm).
>
> By default, annotate writes its output to a file whose file-name extension is `.ann.`

You can find an [example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23266294/6309).

See also "[How to use ClearCase annotate sub-command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7521742/6309)".